# Preview for Unity/Nautilus

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 with Unity.

I would like to have a Preview utility, like on a Mac. If you press Space key while having a file selected in Finder, it will show it in a temporary window. Super useful for a quick preview of text-files/photos/music/videos.

I have found a similar utility for [gnome](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gnome-sushi-quick-previewer-for-nautilus.html), however I am concerned about it breaking Unity.

Does anyone know if this is safe to install on my system, and if not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

gnome-sushi works great with Unity and Nautilus in 14.04.  it should work just as well in 14.10.

Update:  I tested gnome-sushi in 14.10 and it also works there.

Comment: It seems to work, but its not nearly as good as osx preview. Oh well.